# Can someone explain to me where the correlated mutation code get stuck?

Tags: matlab, correlation, nonlinear-optimization, evolutionary-algorithm, mutation

I'm triying to implement evolutionary strategy algorithm with the so called correlated mutation (self-adaptation) where my following Matlab code that I supposed to be correct didnt optimize (sphere benchmark function) as well as I expected.

```
    %% mutate sigma & alpha
 for l = 1:lambda;  

    tmp       = randn(n,n);
    OffspringIndividual.sigma = Recombinant.sigma.*exp(tau_prime*randn + tau*(tmp + tmp'));

    tmp       = rand(n,n);
    OffspringIndividual.alpha = Recombinant.alpha + beta*triu((tmp + tmp'),1);

    %% Coordinate transformation with respect to axes 'i' and 'j' and angle
  R = eye(n);
  for m = 1:n-1
    for q = m+1:n
      T               =  eye(n);
      T([m q], [m q]) =  [  cos(OffspringIndividual.alpha(m,m))     -sin(OffspringIndividual.alpha(m,q))
                            sin(OffspringIndividual.alpha(q,m))      cos(OffspringIndividual.alpha(q,q)) ];
      R               =  R*T;
    end
  end

%   %% mutate object parameter
%   OffspringIndividual.y = Recombinant.y + OffspringIndividual.sigma'  .* randn(n,1); 
   OffspringIndividual.y = Recombinant.y + R*sqrt(diag(diag(OffspringIndividual.sigma)))*randn(n,1);

  %% check boundaries
  for check = 1:n
      if OffspringIndividual.y(check) > ub
          OffspringIndividual.y(check) = ub;
      end
      if OffspringIndividual.y(check) < lb
          OffspringIndividual.y(check) = lb;
      end
  end


  %% determine fitness
  OffspringIndividual.F = fitness(OffspringIndividual.y); 

  %% offspring complete
  OffspringPop{l} = OffspringIndividual;                  
 end;
```

After selecting best Offspring Individual it seems to me that there is no biggest improvment of the fitness function despite it decreases.
Is it any problem with my mutation?

Comment: What do you mean for as well as you expect? Have you compared with other algorithm? What kind of problem are you trying to optimize? You are not giving much details, but rather asking for debug....

Comment: @AndreaCassioli thanks for replying )). I'm optimizing benchmark sphere function `sum(x.*x)` which I know it's minimum 0 and I meant my results are not significant ( I dont know if my mutation steps are correct or not.